# When the Stack Exchange alert is clicked, the app shows a blank screen

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, android-app, alerts

I have recently installed the Stack Exchange app and it's pretty impressive with all functionalities packed inside a small device.

Today when I received one alert from the app & after clicking on it, the app opened but with blank screen (I mean the right slide-in screen with all alerts).

I waited for some time, nothing happened, so I tried refreshing the app, then all the messages/alerts started appearing.

I know this is a beta app, so this isn't a big issue. Hope to see a stable app :)